# Python web scraping outputs none

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to web scraping and I tried to scrape product details from website. But when I run the code, the output is just "none".

CODE -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

web_page = requests.get('https://ikman.lk/en/ads?by_paying_member=0&sort=relevance&buy_now=0&query=iphone%20x&page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.content, 'html.parser')
phone_list = soup.find(id='list--3NxGO')

print(phone_list)
```

`

And the result is -

```
chamindu@Chamindu:~/projects/helloworld$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/chamindu/projects/helloworld/no.py
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace:**

```
phone_list = soup.find(id='list--3NxGO')
```

**With:**

```
phone_list = soup.find("ul", {"class":'list--3NxGO'})
```

Comment: If this answered your question be sure to accept it.